# Open .rar files on Win Vista

Tags: zip, rar

What is the best option to open .rar files on Windows Vista?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the best option to open .rar
>   files on Windows Vista?

**[WinRAR](http://www.rarlab.com/)** is a powerful archive manager. It can backup your data and reduce the size of email attachments, decompress RAR, ZIP and other files.

Comment: pro: polished interface, creators of the compression so must be better supported / con: not free

Comment: @fluxtendu - unRAR is actually free. minus the polished interface, that is :)

Comment: @Molly: unRAR is only free as in cost.

Answer (score 9):

[7-Zip](http://7-zip.org)

Does lots more besides RAR: ZIP and ISO to name a few.

Comment: pro: free & open source / con: unpolished interface

Comment: The unRAR.dll in 7-Zip actually has a license restriction--you can't use it to build a rar archiver.

Comment: True, but OP asked about opening rar files.

Comment: It's true about the unpolished interface... but hey, the program itself is awesome and I never rar files anyway, I 7zip them.

Answer (score 0):

If you like the command line you can install UnRar from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html - it's free and native to Win32.

Comment: It looks funny when I see something GNU to be called native for win :)

Comment: GNU is Not Unix

Answer (score 0):

[IZarc](http://www.izarc.org) which is a free download which supports many archive formats like: 7-ZIP, A, ACE, ARC, ARJ, B64, BH, BIN, BZ2, BZA, C2D, CAB, CDI, CPIO, DEB, ENC, GCA, GZ, GZA, HA, IMG, ISO, JAR, LHA, LIB, LZH, MDF, MBF, MIM, NRG, PAK, PDI, PK3, RAR, RPM, TAR, TAZ, TBZ, TGZ, TZ, UUE, WAR, XXE, YZ1, Z, ZIP, ZOO.

[image]